# Making an image refresh every 10 mins

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Refresh Image PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150577/refresh-image-php-and-javascript)
>   [How to reload img every 5 second using javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572193/how-to-reload-img-every-5-second-using-javascript)

i need an image on my website to refresh every 10 mins, but i dont want it to refresh the whole website

im not even sure if this is possible but if it is can you please help me
many thanks
connor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you want to reload the image, you must change the image url like so: "screen.jpg?rand=123456789" where "123456789" is a randomly generated number, which is regenerated every time you want to reload the image. The browser will think that it is a different image, and actually download it again, instead of retrieve it from the cache. The web server will most likely ignore and discard everything after the question mark.

To cause the reload in the first place, your would have to use Javascript to get the image element and change the source. The easiest option I can see is to give the image element an `id` attribute, like so:

```
<img src="screen.jpg" id="myImage" />
```

Then you may change the source of the image:

```
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = 'screen.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
```

To do this on a set timer, then use the top-level Javascript function `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
    myImageElement.src = 'screen.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
}, 5000);
```

The second argument specifies 5000 milliseconds, which equates to 5 seconds.

This is a quote from: [How to reload img every 5 second using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572193/how-to-reload-img-every-5-second-using-javascript)

This method pretty much describes exactly what you seem to want. All you need to do is change the time.

Comment: Incredible, this is the first useful answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Change the image `src`, add a dummy variable with the current timestamp to the end of the URI, e.g. `foo.jpg?nocache=2934823920`.

Taken from [Refresh Image PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150577/refresh-image-php-and-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot do that with php.

You would need to use javascript and some ajax methods to *refresh* an image

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image in an iframe which refreshes

or this: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/help/archive.php/o_t__t_253__refresh-one-image-only.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the place where javascript may enter. Take a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/), it can help you to make a piece of code that asynchronously "takes" a new picture (calling the same "API", a PHP script that serves the new image each time it is invoked).

Comment: or picking a brand new URL every 10 minutes... it depends on the image being generated or taken from a "static" set or...